# How do I make MySQL MyISAM "strict"?

Tags: mysql

At the end of [this video](http://youtu.be/emgJtr9tIME), the speaker says you can change the default MySQL settings to prevent things like automatically casting a string into integer 0 when inserting a string into an int field, automatic string truncation, and more.

Where are these settings? Do they work on MyISAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this website](http://umumble.com/blogs/mysql/162/) for more information. Hope this helps you.

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE';
```

Comment: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` will not work for MyISAM since it is not a transactional engine. `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` might, with some caveats. See your friendly manual for details.

Comment: @TheVedge: I ran the query exactly as Anon posted it, and it seems to be working perfectly on my MyISAM. Gives errors for poorly formatted dates, inserting into columns without default values, strings that are too long, inserting a string into an int... not sure if I'm missing any cases, but this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Mark That's odd. Documentation says otherwise: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables . Glad it solved your issue though!

Comment: @TheVedge "when possible for nontransactional storage engines". I guess it was possible? You're right though; "STRICT_ALL_TABLES" sounds more appropriate according to the docs.